# Synchronizing in a for each loop still throws ConcurrentModificationExceptions

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

I'm trying to iterate through a loop on one thread, like so:

```
for (UnitTask task : chain) {
    g.drawLine((int) task.getLocation().getX(), (int) task.getLocation().getY(), (int) currentPos.getX(), (int) currentPos.getY());
    g.fillOval((int) task.getLocation().getX() - 2, (int) task.getLocation().getY() - 2, 5, 5);
    currentPos = task.getLocation();
}
```

However, I have another thread (the Swing event thread) which can add to this object. Hence, `ConcurrentModificationException`. I tried obtaining a lock by surrounding the code with `synchronized (chain) { ... }`, but I still get the errors.

As a bit of a Java synchronization newbie, I'm a little confused as to why. I would expect this to make the loop thread-safe, but evidently, it is not.

Interestingly, `chain` is an instance of a custom class, but it is only a thin wrapper around a `LinkedList`. The list itself is private, and there's no way for an external class to retrive it directly (there are methods to explicitly add/remove objects), so I wouldn't expect this to affect the outcome.

Comment: So the ConcurrentModificationException is thrown on the line of code that starts with `for (UnitTask task: ...` even when the entire for-loop is wrapped in `synchronized(chain) { ... }` ?

Comment: @RayToal Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Did you synchronize the list in the other thread?

Comment: @RayToal Oh, wait, is that necessary? Shows what I know about concurrency programming in Java...

Comment: Oh no problem... that's why this site exists. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The meaning of

```
synchronized (c) {
    ... code that uses c ...
}
```

is

- wait for `c` to be unlocked
- lock `c`
- execute the body
- unlock `c`

So if you synchronize in your thread, then your thread will wait for `c` to be unlocked and then dive in.

Now, if you do *not* synchronize the code on the *other* thread that modifies `c`, that code is going to just go ahead and modify `c` without waiting for a lock.  Synchronizing a block in one thread does not make another thread wait for a lock.  If the other thread has a line such as

```
c.add(someOtherTask)
```

that is not in a synchronized block, then it's going to do the add no matter what.  This is the cause of your exception.  It is also the reason why you saw the exception even though you put the code in your thread in a synchronized block: your code was "playing by the rules" but the other thread couldn't have cared less.

Be careful about synchronizing long-running code though.  You are better off, as Stephen C says, to use a concurrent collection type.

Comment: Thanks, this explains a lot. I eventually opted to go for [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) because it's faster and it's supported in Java 6. Still, I'm glad I at least understand Java's lock system now.

Comment: ... and CLQ doesn't throw CME. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Synchronization will not necessarily help.

Basically the problem is that you are using a collection type that does not allow the collection to be modified while an iteration is in progress (except via the iterator's `remove` method ... if supported).  This is not a threading / synchronization issue *per se*.  (And if you try to solve it simply by synchronization, you may introduce another problem.)

If you want to be able to iterate and modify at the same time, you will need to use a different collection type such as [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) instead of `LinkedList`.

---

> If the iteration and writing are happening on separate threads, then shouldn't synchronizing block the writing until the iteration is finished? Or am I missing something?

The problem will be in how you have implemented the synchronization:

- If you are not explicitly doing some kind synchronization in your `LinkedList` version, then no synchronization is done for you.
- If you use a synchronization wrapper created by one of the `Collections.synchronizedXxx` methods, then the javadocs for those methods clearly state that an `Iterator` object returned by the wrapper's `iterator()` method IS NOT synchronized.
- If you are doing the synchronization by hand, then you have to make sure that everything is synchronizing on the same mutex.  And that lock has to be held on that mutex for the duration of the iteration ... not just for the call the `iterator()`.

And note that if you hold a lock for a long time (e.g. while you are iterating a long list), this can potentially block other threads that need to update the list for a long time.  That kind of thing can be a concurrency bottleneck that can (in the worst case) reduce your system's performance to the speed of a single processor.

The `ConcurrentXxx` classes typically avoid this by relaxing the consistency guarantees for the sequences produced by the iterators.  For instance, you may not see elements that were added to the collection after you started the iteration.

Comment: If the iteration and writing are happening on separate threads, then shouldn't synchronizing block the writing until the iteration is finished? Or am I missing something?